# Devise + Heroku login sometimes fails, no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, devise

About half the time when I push to Heroku, Devise stops letting me login for a seemingly random length of time.  I can fix this either by waiting for more than 10 minutes (time varies) or sometimes by pushing again.

While this login issue is happening there is nothing in the logs to indicate anything is wrong and nothing in the flash when I get redirected back to the login form.  I'm not sure what else to look for or what could be causing this.  Because of the strange time limits I thought it might have something to do with the tmp folder being pushed but it's listed correctly in .gitignore.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 0):

At the time you posted this, Heroku was having problems... I wonder if THAT was the problem?

see 
https://status.heroku.com/
and scroll down the Oct 22.

FWIW for free you can add new relic basic version and setup a monitoring process that emails you when your app is having trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  My problem was reproducible daily and was only with the login action going through the devise form.  I have some api actions setup that were handling login fine going directly to warden.  I ended up just changing the login form to use my api login function for everything and haven't had a problem since.

Comment: Hi pdenya, I am having the same issue. when I try to login I will be redirected to 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in'. I am not seeing any error message in my console. Don't know what exactly is the issue. Please help if you know the solution.